# LabelFor is showing property name instead of Display attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

My model is:

```
public class MyMessage
{
    [Required, Display(Name= "Recipient Id")]
    public string Recipient;
    [Required, Display(Name ="Message")]
    public string Text;
}
```

My view is:

```
@model MyMessage

@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Recipient)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Recipient)
<br/>
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Text)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Text)
```

The rendered output is showing the property name instead of the Display attribute.  What have I done wrong?

Comment: Have you rebuilt the project since adding the Display attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the fields in your model to properties

```
public class MyMessage
{
    [Required, Display(Name= "Recipient Id")]
    public string Recipient { get; set; }
    [Required, Display(Name ="Message")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

The `ModelMetadata.DisplayName` is not set for fields. And you need to do this anyway because the `DefaultModelBinder` does not set the value of fields, so when you submit the form, the values of `Recipient` and `Text` would have been `null` despite what text you entered in the textboxes and `ModelState` would have been invalid because of the `[Required]` attributes